# Treatment Vs control analysis with two groups

Tags: r, anova, t-test

I have cancer and WT controls samples from two different groups for size comparison.
I would like to do some statistics to calculate p-value and perhaps get some plots. I am not very familiar with statistical analysis and was pondering if someone could teach me how to analyze this type of data. Thanks for your time.
my data:

```
df <- structure(list(Group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), cancer = c(0.7, 
0.7, 0.6, 0.65, 1, 0.75, 0.3), WTcontrol = c(1.1, 0.8, 0.7, 1.4, 
1, 1, 1.05)), .Names = c("Group", "cancer", "WTcontrol"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

or

```
Group   cancer  WTcontrol
1        0.7    1.1
1        0.7    0.8
1        0.6    0.7
2        0.65   1.4
2        1      1
2        0.75   1
2        0.3    1.05
```

Comment: You only have 7 persons in your data?

Comment: @peteR That is right.

Comment: Each person has a cancer score and a WT control score? Or what doe the numbers mean? And Group 1 got a treatment and Group 2 not?

Comment: And what exactly do you want to test now

Comment: @peteR These numbers are the cell size(in micrometer). I want to see if the cancer is significant to control. So want to get p-value.

Comment: @peteR Group 1 and Group 2 are two experiments performed at two time points.

Comment: Do you want to perform a test for each of the two time points? Why is there one cell more in time 2, its not the same cells as in time1 ?

Comment: @peteR Group2 has 1 extra replicate.

Comment: @Yes I would like to perform a test for each of the two time points.

Answer (score 1):

With such a small sample size it is extremely hard to test if conditions for tests such as ANOVA or t-test are met. However, t-test was for example designed to correct for small samples. What I want to tell you is that you should be aware of the fact that drawing conclusions on such small samples must be treated cautiously. 
Here is the code for (Welch's) t-test.

```
df = structure(list(Group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L),
                 cancer = c(0.7, 0.7, 0.6, 0.65, 1, 0.75, 0.3),
                 WTcontrol = c(1.1, 0.8, 0.7, 1.4, 1, 1, 1.05)),
                 .Names = c("Group", "cancer", "WTcontrol"),
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))

exp1 = df[df$Group==1,]
exp2 = df[df$Group == 2, ]

t.test(exp1$cancer,exp1$WTcontrol)
t.test(exp2$cancer,exp2$WTcontrol)
```

And it results in:

```
Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  exp1$cancer and exp1$WTcontrol
t = -1.6036, df = 2.3059, p-value = 0.2335
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
-0.6738719  0.2738719
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
0.6666667 0.8666667
```

and experiment 2

```
 Welch Two Sample t-test

 data:  exp2$cancer and exp2$WTcontrol
 t = -2.5107, df = 5.2222, p-value = 0.05174
 alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
 95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.879763277  0.004763277
 sample estimates:
 mean of x mean of y 
 0.6750    1.1125
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Also, how do you compare between the tow time points? Meaning, if time is significant or not?

Comment: Also, how do you plot this?

Comment: Plotting does not make sense as your sample size is too small for boxplots or sth like that.

Comment: It depends on what you want. Do you want to compare the difference in time for both cancer and WT or for each seperately?

Comment: I actually want both. compare the difference in time as well compare them separately.

Comment: Compare time for both groups together:
t.test(df[1:3,2:3],df[4:7,2:3])
Compare time for both groups separately:
t.test(df[1:3,2],df[4:7,2]) and
t.test(df[1:3,3],df[4:7,3])